# Trying to make a GUI to query a MySql database

Tags: mysql

What language would be best for this? I'm not trying to make a website front end, just want to make queries easier. I have heard some say R is good but I find the initial setup really weird and I cant figure out how to make GUI's either.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Use C++ and Qt with QMYSQL. This is the best language. Others may disagree, but they are wrong.

Comment: Make queries easier how?